# Programatically change ip address of DSL connection

Tags: networking

I'm working on a project for my company. I'm using a DSL connection. My IP address changes every time I restart my router. Is there a faster way to request a new IP from my ISP programatically? I've seen that RDSL services can change the IP in a few seconds, but I'm looking for a more "legal" way to do this other than RDSL.
Thank you!

Comment: Talk to your provider, I can't see how this is programming related.

Comment: Invest in an IP-controllable power strip and send the commands there?  We ended up actually doing this on a flaky connection at work.  It was utterly hacktastic, but it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your router have firmware you can browse to?  There may be a link to reboot your router (or even release/renew your IP lease) there.  You can set up a cron job to call cURL to access that URL every so often.  You might also have to authenticate in order to do that, but cURL should handle that.

If you're on a system that does not have cURL or cron, you may have equivalents, but they're pretty simple programs and you should be able to find them for any popular OS.